# C# set inherited class equal to base class

Tags: c#

if I have a parent class:

```
public class ParentClass
{
  public string ParentStr = string.empty;
}
```

and a child class:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
  public string ChildStr = string.empty;
}
```

Say later in my code I have an instance of ParentClass

```
ParentClass parentClass = New ParentClass() { ParentStr = "something" }
```

Is it possible to create an instance of the ChildClass from the ParentClass? Something to the effect of:

```
ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass)parentClass
```

Comment: You got your "Is A" relationship backwards - back to the OO fundamentals

Comment: didn't allow me to edit anymore: In your case the childClass `is a` parentClass, that means you can assign instances of childclass to variables of type parentclass (not the other way round)

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you could provide an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) or [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) operator to do this, though it seems pretty weird.

Subclassing defines an is-a relationship, but the subclass is-a superclass, not the other way around.  Without knowing what your classes are, I think you've got design issues outside of this.

Comment: +1 for "the subclass is-a superclass, not the other way around". Children are their parents; parents are not their children.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it in English terms: if your parent class is an `Animal` and the child class is a `Dog`, can you say, without any doubt, that an `Animal` is a `Dog`?

Answering a question with another question is not great, so the real answer is: no, you cannot cast an instance of a base class into a child class.

However, if you stored an instance of the child class in a variable of the type of the base class, you are allowed to cast it back to the child class. The following is valid:

```
ParentClass p = new ChildClass();
ChildClass  c = (ChildClass)p;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. ChildClass is a different type, and you can't cast an actual runtime instance of the ParentClass to the ChildClass.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the purpose? If such a construct existed, then the new `ChildClass` would, I suppose, just have the default values for any properties that extended `ParentClass`. Just create a `ChildClass` object to begin with.

You can always use a base class type container for inherited classes. You should not be trying to recreate an instance of an object to a derived type, instead, you should be creating an instance of the derived type, and using the base type container if you want to be able to interchange the objects:

```
ParentClass parentClass = new *ChildClass*() { ParentStr = "something" } 
ChildClass childClass = (ChildClass)parentClass
```

I am not recommending these naming conventions :)

Comment: Here's *my* reason: I've inherited code where the coder had stored a bunch of database data in 2D arrays. I want to replace them with DataTables, but I still want the code to build in the interim. As a crutch while I'm re-coding stuff, I created an adapter to DataTable (a subclass) that provides a default 2-index property (which, of course, I've marked with the `Obsolete` attribute). Because I intend to transition to standard DataTables, there are some points where this would be helpful, like assigning from `ToTable()` in DataTableExtensions.